# Problemas com click em elementos filhos da div

Tags: javascript

Estou a desenvolver um projeto onde cria dinamicamente, varias div com a class "musicItem" e para cada div eu tenho associado um data-musicId, e também tenho um evento de clique nessa div que ao clicar faço algumas ações mas para isso preciso de saber o "data-musicid", o problema é que seu eu clicar na div tudo ocorre perfeitamente, mas se clicar em algum elemento filho dela dá erro. Seria possível resolver este problema com o javascript vanilla, sem jquery?

Codigo de detecção de clicks na div:

```
const musicItens = document.querySelectorAll('.musicItem');
    for (const music of musicItens) {
        music.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            const clickedmusic = event.target.attributes['data-musicid'].value;
            this.play(clickedmusic);
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

Filhos da Div:

```
        <div class="musicItem" data-musicid="1">
        <div class="musicPhoto">
            <img src="assets/images/3348986.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="musicData">
            <p>Malha Suprema - Judas</p>
            <p>ACERT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="btnPlayer">
            <button class="playerBtn">
                <span class="playerImg">
                    <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                </span>                 
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cara pelo que entendi vc quer que ao clicar em um elemento com a classe `musicItem` vc que saber o `data-musicid` e dar um `.play()` nele confere?

Comment: Sim chamar a função play()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que quando você emite um evento em um elemento que contém elementos filhos que também contém eventos, ao clicar em um elemento filho, o evento `click` do elemento pai também é disparado.

Para arrumar isso, você pode adicionar um `event.stopPropagation();`

Ficaria algo do tipo:

```js
music.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: O problema é que eu quero detectar o click em tudo incluindo nos elementos filhos e por isso é que eu apliquei logo na div pai, para os filhos também herdarem o click e poderem me retornar o data-musicid do pai, mas os filhos estão me a retornar Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @Tomás, então, testei aqui e o problema é que o evento `click` está sendo referenciado no elemento que você está clicando, por exemplo, quando você clica na imagem, ele tenta pegar o atributo `data-musicid` da imagem, e não existe este atributo nela. Para resolver, você faz o seguinte: troca `const clickedmusic = event.target.attributes...` por `const clickedmusic = music.attributes["data-musicid"].value;`

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas Bittencourt era esse o problema!